# Write the closed interval [a,b] as the intersection of semi-intervals of the form [a,b).

Tags: real-analysis

I want to express all intervals as countable union or intersection of intervals of the form $[a, b)$.

This is what I have.

$$ (a,b) = \bigcup_{n} [a - \frac{1}{n}, b)$$

$$ [a,b] = \bigcup_{n} (a, b - \frac{1}{n})$$

$$ (a,b] = \bigcup_{n} (a+\frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ [a,b] = \bigcup_{n} (a, b - \frac{1}{n})$$
can't be correct. $a$ is to be supposed to be in the resulting interval but is not included in any of the intervals being intersected.

$$ (a,b] = \bigcup_{n} (a+\frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n})$$

Why do you subtract ${1 \over n}$ from $b$?